# PublicKeyToken null was not found

Tags: c#, deserialization

I created my first windows form application C# 4.5

I publish the app under `C:\` 
So I installed the app with the `.exe` under that path.

The application serializes tables in binary files and then transfers these files to a remote server.
All works well: creation > compression > ftp transfer.

Now when i try to `deserialize` with a ASP.NETt I get the error:

> The assembly 'myApplication, Version = 1.0.0.0, Culture = neutral, PublicKeyToken =
>   null'  was not found.

As a serializer, I'm using `BinaryFormatter`.

What does that error mean?

Both the application (Windows Form) and ASP.NET site are in 4.5 .
What should I do?

This is the deserialize code:

```
public long Deserialize(SqlConnection ImportConnection)
{

    String path = Path.Combine(HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath, "unZIP/AGENTI.bin");
    long position = 0;      
    BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    long blocchi = 0;
    using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        while (position < stream.Length)
        {
            stream.Seek(position, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            var listAgenti = (List<AGENTI>)formatter.Deserialize(stream);

            position = stream.Position;

            foreach (AGENTI agente in listAgenti)
            {
                agente.InsertAgenti(ImportConnection, agente);
            }
            blocchi++;
        }
        stream.Flush();
    }

    return blocchi;
}
```

Inside file.bin i found
... HApp_Code.kwqligxt, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null   uSystem.Collections.Generic.List`1[[AGENTI,....

The code before was in an ASP.NET site for serialization and it worked,
now it is inside Windows Forms nothing has changed.

Comment: Please, provide the relevant code

Comment: Can you post your code? Cheers